# Path of ACM cert while connecting to Solr servers which run off https

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, solr, pysolr, aws-acm

I am trying to connect to solr servers which runs on AWS EC2 instances with custom authentication using: https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/tree/5c3a68447734e77be9e9648b184f8d600fd661c5

```
solr = pysolr.Solr('https://path_to_the_loadbalancer/solr/collection_name',
                   auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'), verify=path/to/cert.perm)
```

Question:
how to give the cert path if the cert exist in AWS ACM?

I tried keeping verify=False which worked, but I wanted to find out the right approach of providing cert

Answer (score 0):

There is no cert path, because the certificate is not on the local server. You can't use an ACM certificate in this scenario.

Comment: If I can not access the ACM cert then how do I connect to the Zookeeper:

```zookeeper = pysolr.ZooKeeper("my_zkhost1:2181/solr, zkhost2:2181,...,zkhostN:2181")
solr = pysolr.SolrCloud(zookeeper, "collection", verify=False)```

This gives me timeout Error:
Connection dropped: socket connection error: None
Failed connecting to Zookeeper within the connection retry policy.
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kazoo/client.py", line 635, in start
    raise self.handler.timeout_exception("Connection time-out")
kazoo.handlers.threading.KazooTimeoutError: Connection time-out